# "if" loop nested into a "for" loop does not work as expected

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement

Long story short I have this exercise to complete:

> In Robert McCloskey’s book Make Way for Ducklings, the names of the
> ducklings are Jack, Kack, Lack, Mack, Nack, Ouack, Pack, and Quack.
> This loop tries to output these names in order.
>
> Of course, that’s not quite right because Ouack and Quack are
> misspelled. Can you fix it?

The code that I've been given:

```
prefixes = "JKLMNOPQ"
suffix = "ack"

for p in prefixes:
    print(p + suffix)
```

After different try I managed to solve it like that:

```
prefixes = "JKLMNOPQ"
suffix = "ack"

for p in prefixes:
    if p=="O" or p=="Q":
        print(p + "u" + suffix)        
    else:            
         print(p + suffix)
```

It looks a little bit too much "hardcode" to me. Do you think it is a valid solution ?

Then I tried, just for the sake of comprehension, to do something similar by myself.
So I wrote the following code:

```
list=["ABCD"]
for l in list:
    if l =="A" or l=="B":
        print("ok")
    else:
        print(l)
```

Basically I want it to print "ok" when L is equal to A or B and L (so "C" and "D") otherwise.
But instead the output is:

```
ABCD
```

If I delete the last print command, no output is printed.
What's wrong ? It looks pretty similar to the one I solved but still it doesn't work as I expect.
What am I missing ?
Thank you guys, and happy new year.

Comment: Hi, as you have now answers now, you may think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to reward the one that gives you the most helpful comment.

Answer (score 1):

In your first code, `prefixes = "JKLMNOPQ"` is one string, so when iterating on it, you iterate over its char. But then with `list=["ABCD"]` its a list of ONE element, so when iterating on it you have only one element who is `ABCD`

```
values = "ABCD"
for l in values:
    if l in "AB":
        print("ok")
    else:
        print(l)
```

Also `if p=="O" or p=="Q"` can be replaced by `if p in "PQ"`. you can also put the `if` directly inside the print call

```
prefixes = "JKLMNOPQ"
suffix = "ack"
for p in prefixes:
    print(p + ("u" if p in "PQ" else "") + suffix)
```

Answer (score 0):

It might help to think of a string as a list of characters. When you iterate over a string, you get each character:

```py
for x in "myteststring":
    print(x)
```

When you iterate over a list, you get each element. So a list of one element, the string `"ABCD"` looks like `["ABCD"]`, but the first element is `"ABCD"`, not `"A"`:

```py
for x in ["myteststring"]:
    print(x)
```

What you probably want is to iterate over a list of many strings:

```py
for x in ["A", "B", "C", "D"]:
   print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined the list as an array of strings. The loop will only be executed once with l = "ABDC"

The correct code should look like

```
list="ABCD"
for l in list:
    if l =="A" or l=="B":
        print("ok")
    else:
        print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

It prints ABCD because you are taking `list = ["ABCD"]`. Now when you iterate over the elements, your L will be 'ABCD'. Thus it will go to else block and will print ABCD.

```
ist="ABCD"
for l in ist:
    if l =="A" or l=="B":
        print("ok")
    else:
        print(l)
```

I have changed 'list' to 'ist' because it is not a good practice to use variable name same as the built-in functions.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all valid answers above, you can keep your list as it is and get the first item of it in you loop :

```
mylist=["ABCD"]
for l in mylist[0]:
    if l =="A" or l=="B":
        print("ok")
    else:
        print(l)
```

And please avoid using list as the name of your variables because list is a keyword in python.